# How to change time zone in a bash script?

Tags: linux, date

I am working on Linux Ubuntu, and I want a bash script whose output is to convert the timezone 7 hours in advance from my server time.

My server time:

> Mon Jul 23 23:00:00 2017

What I want to achieve:

> Mon Jul 24 06:00:00 2017

I have tried this one in my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

let var=$(date +%H)*3600+$(date +%M)*60+$(date +%S)
seven=25200
time=$(($var+$seven))

date=$(date --date='TZ="UTC+7"' "+%Y-%m-%d")
hours=$(date -d@$time -u +%H:%M:%S)

echo "$date" "$hours"
```

the output was:

> 2017-07-23
>   06:00:00

The hours works, but the date still matches the server date. Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your question literally, if you just want to get a date string for 7 hours later than the current time in the current zone, that's easy:

```
date -d "7 hours" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

If what you're really wanting to do is pull the local date/time in some other timezone, though, then you'd be better off following the advice in some of the other answers.

Comment: thanks I tried this one and it works, and yeah I am trying to pull the local time zone in other timezone, it works using this `DATE=$(TZ=Asia/Bangkok date +"%FI%H:%M")`

Answer (score 14):

You can change the time zone for the entire script by changing the `TZ` environment variable early in the script. It can be overridden on individual commands.

For example this script

```
#!/bin/bash
export TZ=Australia/Sydney

date
TZ=US/Pacific date
date
```

Will output

```
Sun 30 Jul 21:56:25 AEST 2017
Sun 30 Jul 04:56:25 PDT 2017
Sun 30 Jul 21:56:25 AEST 2017
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want "AEST" or "PDT" on my output, well I have found the solution, I am using `DATE=$(TZ=Asia/Bangkok date +"%FI%H:%M")`

Comment: Be careful that the timezone you're interested in is entered accurately, or `date` will silently default to UTC. `TZ=foo date` yields `Wed Aug  5 19:30:05 foo 2020` (which happens to be UTC).

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked in the quoting section in `man bash` ?
I believe something like 
`DATE=$( date --date="TZ=\"Asia/Taipei\" $TIME" +%F\ %H:%M )` 
is what you're looking for.  Can anyone second that for me?

Comment: If you need *now* in Taipei, this `DATE=$(TZ=Asia/Taipei date +"%F %H:%M")` shoud be easier

Comment: Okay I will try this and look for the result tomorrow. Thanks for the reply by the way, hope it works

Comment: @AlexeyTen 's thanks I think this is more accurate